# Add own poststep to Debian package - postrm.debhelper

Tags: ubuntu, package, deb, dpkg, debhelper

In my debian-folder of my debian package I want to add an post-step that removes a directory for example.

I think the file ***.postrm.debhelper** is right for that. But this file will overwritten by several helperscripts (dh_installinit, dh_icons).

How can I add own actions to these scripts, that they will merged with the commands, which will auto-generated?

**Update**: I see in the manpage of [dh_installdeb](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dh_installdeb.1.html), that i have to add **#DEBHELPER#** as placeholder. But even i do that at the end of the file like this, my whole file will be overwritten:

```
#My own commentar
echo "My own action"

#DEBHELPER#
```

**Update 2**: dh_clean and dh_prep execute

```
rm -rf package.*.debhelper
```

following they shift script-samples from */usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts/* into the postrm.debhelper script.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

Rename file: [packagename].postrm.debhelper ==> [packagename].postrm

After that *My own commentar* will be stored above the auto-generated commands, which will placed on the **#DEBHELPER#** placeholder.

```
#My own commentar
echo "My own action"

#DEBHELPER#
```